# Independent domination number for grid graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-domination

Let $G_{n,m}$ be the $n \times m$ grid graph, i.e. $G= P_n \Box P_m$, and $T_{n,m}$ the $n\times m$ torus grid graph, i.e. $G= C_n \Box C_m$, where $P_n$ and $C_n$ indicate the path graph of length $n$ and the cycle graph of length $n$, respectively. The *independent domination number* $i(G)$ is deﬁned to be the minimum cardinality among all maximal independent sets of vertices of $G$.

Is there any explicit formula for $i(G_{n,m})$ and $i(T_{n,m})$? If not, is there a lower bound sharper than the one given by corresponding domination numbers $\gamma(G_{n,m})$ and $\gamma(T_{n,m})$? Or is there any asymptotic results for $i(G_{n,m})/mn$ and $i(T_{n,m})/mn$ as $m,n \to \infty$?

Comment: You might be able to glean some info from the paper "[The Number of Independent Sets in a Grid Graph](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=288860)," which, as the title indicates, is focused on the number rather than the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The independent domination number of grid graphs is known. You can find what you are looking for in the following paper.

S. Crevals and P.R.J. Ostergard, Independent domination of grids, Discrete Math. 338 (2015), 1379-1384.